How to use local jar to avoid downloading a plugin in gradle
This is a company plugin, hosted on maven central and is base of our all projects/sub-modules to start working with it.
A typical settings.gradle file of base app looks like this:
pluginManagement {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral() {
      content {
        excludeGroup 'com.companyname'
      }
    }
    maven {
      url 'https://repository.companyname.com/link/to/repository/maven-public/'
    }
  }
  plugins {
    id 'com.companyname.app' version '7.1.1'
  }
}

plugins {
  id 'com.github.node-gradle.node' version '3.5.1' apply false
}


dependencyResolutionManagement {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral() {
      content {
        excludeGroup 'com.companyname'
      }
    }
    maven {
      url 'https://repository.companyname.com/link/to/repository/maven-public/'
    }
    // Declare the Node.js download repository
    ivy {
      name = "Node.js"
      setUrl("https://nodejs.org/dist/")
      patternLayout {
        artifact("v[revision]/[artifact](-v[revision]-[classifier]).[ext]")
      }
      metadataSources {
        artifact()
      }
      content {
        includeModule("org.nodejs", "node")
      }
    }
  }
}

//Include all modules
rootProject.name = "companyname-productname"

def modules = []
file("modules").traverse(type: groovy.io.FileType.DIRECTORIES, maxDepth: 1) { it ->
  if (new File(it, "build.gradle").exists()) {
    modules.add(it)
  }
}

gradle.ext.appModules = modules

modules.each { dir ->
  include "modules:$dir.name"
  project(":modules:$dir.name").projectDir = dir
}


and a build.gradle file of base app looks like this:
plugins {
  id 'com.companyname.app'
}

companyname {
  title "CompanyName ProductName"
  description "CompanyName Enterprise Application"
}

allprojects {
  apply plugin: 'idea'
  apply plugin: 'eclipse'

  group = 'com.companyname.apps'
  version = '7.1.5'

  java {
    toolchain {
      languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(11)
    }
  }

  afterEvaluate {
    test {
      useJUnitPlatform()
      beforeTest { descriptor ->
        logger.lifecycle('Running: ' + descriptor)
      }
    }
  }

  configurations {
    runtimeClasspath.exclude group: "org.eclipse.birt.runtime.3_7_1", module: "org.apache.commons.codec"
  }
}

tasks.withType(PublishToMavenRepository).configureEach { it.enabled = false }

dependencies {
  gradle.appModules.each { dir ->
    implementation project(":modules:$dir.name")
  }
}

and build.gradle of any sub-module looks like this:
plugins {
    id 'com.companyname.app'
}

companyname {
    title "companyname :: companyname accounting"
    description "companyname accounting module"
}

dependencies {

    // module dependencies
    api "com.companyname.apps:module-1:5.0.0"
    api "com.companyname.apps:module-2:7.1.0"
    
}



In case of working with new cloned instance of a module, the first time build fetches the jars, but sometimes there is an issue of server timeout, due to slow server response.
I have the requires jars locally available, but no clue how to use them as it uses them as plugin instead of dependencies.
